# Git cache ssh key in windows (PutTTy)

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh, putty

I have set
 1-Environment variable GIT_SSH to C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe
 2-Set Pageant + pkey in start up and even can see the key in system try
 3-installed git based on plink.
Once I could cache the key in the registry, but later, when I tried to pull, it asked me to cache key again. When I opened registry under  HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/SimonTatham/PuTTY/SshHostkey/ I saw the key, but still git bash freezes . Even when I delete the key from the registry and reopen putty and save the key in registry, it reappears in the registry again but still Git Bash is freezing.
[the screenshot can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWHft.png)

Any Idea?

Comment: *"asked me to cache key again"* and *"freezes"* - Are these referring to the same behavior? Or are these different? Please be clear. Show us some screenshots or transcripts.

Comment: git for the first connection will ask to cache the key. it was work properly at the cloning time, then when i want to pull anything , will ask me to cache key again , and it will freeze